# Is it doable to run a batch file automatically when a user logins to Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, authentication, login-script

I would like to automate running a custom batch file when a user logins to Windows 8? Is it possible?

Thanks,
Racoon

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/463169/windows-8-run-script-on-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Task Scheduler.  Here's a resource I found by Googling this (It also applies to Windows 8, though of course the interface is different): http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7